# Intellij recommends initialization without variable name

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While working on my project I found this recommandation made by Intellij. It removed my variable declaration.

[Here is a picture with the pop-up message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn8f7.png)

Intellij transformed my code from:

```
    public void start() throws IOException {
        JSONObject yearJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject regionJson = new JSONObject();
```

to

```
    public void start() throws IOException {
        new JSONObject();
        new JSONObject();
```

Here is my full code :

```
    public void start() throws IOException {
        new JSONObject();
        new JSONObject();
        JSONArray yearArray = new JSONArray();

        String basePath = "/Users/andrei/AplicatieLicenta/censusOutput/";
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

        File file;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        JSONObject yearJsonObject = new JSONObject();

        for (String year : years) {
            yearJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            yearJsonObject.put("year", year);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            for (String region : regions) {
                path = new StringBuilder();
                path.append(basePath).append(year).append("/").append(region).append("/result");

                file = new File(path.toString());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                JSONObject regionData = new JSONObject();
                regionData.put("region", region);
                String line;

                JSONArray values = new JSONArray();

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONObject demographics = new JSONObject();
                    demographics.put("value", getJsonFromLine(line));
                    values.add(demographics);
                }
                regionData.put("demographics", values);
                jsonArray.add(regionData);
                yearJsonObject.put("data", jsonArray);
            }
            yearArray.add(yearJsonObject);
        }
        parentJson.put("years", yearArray);
        System.out.println(parentJson);
    }
```

It still works and does exactly the same thing but I can't understand why. I searched online about this and didn't find anything, not even close.

Comment: I think the reason for that is that these 2 variables are never used. But instead of just deleting them, intellij recognizes that when they are initialized, stuff (`ew JSONObject()`) happens. So just removing the whole line would remove the "stuff" too, which is what intellij tries to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those were unused variables, so IntelliJ suggested deleting them. The call to `new JSONObject()` might have had side effects, so it kept those; you can delete them. (Better, use something like Jackson and make your JSON handling much simpler.)